# How to validate and store list of objects in Laravel

Tags: android, laravel, phpstorm, retrofit

I have a Retrofit API call to my Laravel server:

```
@POST("/dualsimlog")
Call<ResponseBody> submitLogs(@Body List<ServerLog> serverLogs);
```

Here is the Retrofit implementation:

```
List<ServerLog> unsubmitted = logHelper.getLogInfo();
retrofit2.Call<ResponseBody> call = logServices.submitLogs(unsubmitted);

                    call.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<ResponseBody> call, retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                            L.m(response.message());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                            L.m("Submission failed.");
                        }
                    });
```

My Laravel store API for a single object is:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // validating object variables
        $rules = [
            'device_id' => 'required|string',
            'type' => 'required|string',
            'sim1_cost' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
            'sim2_cost' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
            'cost_saved' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
            'call_duration' => 'required|numeric|min:0',
            'created_at' => 'required|date',
        ];

        $data = $request->all();
        $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $this->errorResponse("Validation error.",400 );
        }
        $product = DualSimLog::create($data);

        return $this->showMessage("Successful.");
    }
```

How to modify the API to validate and insert the list of `ServerLog` objects?

Moreover how to debug Laravel projects in PhpStorm when using Android for sending the API request?

Comment: 1) Debugging manuals: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm -- IDE does not care what framework it is -- it debugs PHP code. 2) Assuming that debugging PHP code will be done using Xdebug. Since you unlikely will be able to modify request itself (to add "debug me" flag) .. you can do that on server side --- either by adding `xdebug_break();` into your code .. or configuring xdebug to attempt to debug every single request automatically (`xdebug.remote_autostart=1` in php.ini).

Answer (score 0):

you need use @FormUrlEncoded in retrofit, see this [link](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-data-form-urlencoded)

Comment: but how to validate the list and store them?